# Strange bug when dealing with VBA Solver on another sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I got this very strange bug when I used Solver via VBA. My objective and changing cells are on sheet 1 and whenever I got one optimized solution, I'd like to copy the optimized changing cells to sheet 2 (I do this several times because each time my optimization function changes). If I added `Worksheets(1).Select` in my Solver program, then Solver works fine and pastes the values to sheet 2 well. However, if I deleted this statement and ran Solver with sheet 2 selected rather than sheet 1, then I first saw something like "Setting Up Problems..." in status bar then I got wrong results and also a strange "0" in my sheet 2. I used VBA debugger and found that this "0" value appeared after statement `Call SolverSolve(True)`, so I suspect the bug is just in Solver. Is it a must to run Solver only if the active sheet resides changing cells and objective cell? Or where have I done wrong?

```
Option Explicit
Function SAMPLEONCE()
'Create one sample from 2500 MI data in worksheets("P2 MI Data"), the sample is
'stored in worksheets("P2 Sample")

    Const n As Long = 2500
    Dim temp As Long
    Randomize
    temp = Int(Rnd * 2500) + 1
    SAMPLEONCE = Worksheets("P2 MI Data").Cells(temp + 1, 1).Resize(1, 6)
End Function

Sub SolveItOnce()

    Call solverreset
    Call solverok(Worksheets("P2 Sample").Range("Output"), 2, 0, Worksheets("P2 Sample").Range("Input"))
    Call solversolve(True)
End Sub
Sub SolveIt()
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, k As Long
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    Worksheets("P2 Sample").Activate
    For i = 1 To 100
        'Sampling
        For j = 1 To 1000
            Worksheets("P2 Sample").Range("Sample").Rows(j).FormulaArray = "=SAMPLEONCE()"
        Next j
        Worksheets("P2 Sample").Range("Sample").Copy
        Worksheets("P2 Sample").Range("Sample").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
        'Call Solver
        For k = 1 To 3
            Call SolveItOnce
        Next k
        'Output result
        Worksheets("P2 Sample").Range("A2:G2").Copy
        Worksheets("P2 Result").Range("A1:G1").Offset(i, 0).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    Next i
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
End Sub
```

Comment: there are several quirks with using Solver in VBA. See the answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36671991/use-solver-in-vba-with-loop-in-rows). There's things like - don't use SolverReset, getting the addresses correct, not using `EngineDesc`, that will all have an impact on what you are doing.

Comment: Can I comment on my question specifically?

Comment: Not sure I understand - of course you can comment on your question. If you post a sample of your code, I can provide more direct feedback.

Comment: Just posted. @OldUgly SolveIt() is the main sub, it calls SAMPLEONCE() and SolveItOnce(). It really doesn't hard to read even my code is a bit long, they are mostly very simple oeprations.

Comment: You are inserting SAMPLEONCE as a formula into the range "Sample". Do you have trouble with this updating when you don't want it to?

Comment: are you going to do the "same" solve every time or are they completely different? For as good as all cases it is better (faster) to create a sub to do the solve internally instead of changing values in the worksheet... however, this only is valuable if the pattern itself stays the same. Would it be a possibility to solve it without solver?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't reviewed the complete code, but dealing with the routine `SolveItOnce` ...

```
Sub SolveItOnce()

    Call solverreset
    Call solverok(Worksheets("P2 Sample").Range("Output"), 2, 0, Worksheets("P2 Sample").Range("Input"))
    Call solversolve(True)
End Sub
```

There is a (for lack of a better word) [bug associated with the use SolverReset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36683180/using-solver-in-vba-sets-calculation-mode-to-manual?lq=1). I recommend you omit it. Your call to SolverOK will set your problem up.

When calling SolverOK, the input for `SetCell` and for `ByChange` need to be strings, not ranges. Also, to ensure that solver is referencing the correct sheet, it is best to "fully qualify" the range in the string with the sheet name. I recommend your code look something like this (compiled but not tested) ...

```
Sub SolveItOnce()
Dim myRng As Range, SetAddress As String, ChngAddress As String

    Set myRng = Worksheets("P2 Sample").Range("Output")
    SetAddress = Split(myRng.Address(external:=True), "[")(0) & Split(myRng.Address(external:=True), "]")(1)

    Set myRng = Worksheets("P2 Sample").Range("Input")
    ChngAddress = Split(myRng.Address(external:=True), "[")(0) & Split(myRng.Address(external:=True), "]")(1)

    SolverOk SetCell:=SetAddress, MaxMinVal:=3, ValueOf:=1, ByChange:=ChngAddress, Engine:=1
    SolverSolve UserFinish:=True

    Set myRng = Nothing
End Sub
```

This should prevent interaction between what Solver is doing and what you are doing in the calling routine.

Setting `Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual` won't really do anything for you. Solver requires the calculation mode to be automatic and sets it that way. If you have volatile formula (e.g. something that uses `RAND()`, or `NOW()`, or `RANDBETWEEN()`, etc) you will need to do some other tricks.

**Updated - for problems with changing the active sheet**

I was able to force Solver to recognize that the `SetCell` and `ByChange` addresses were on a sheet other than the active sheet (surprisingly difficult), and it threw the following errors ...

[image]

[image]

Which puts us back to activating the worksheet containing the solver problem before running solver. The following will save whatever your old active sheet was and re-activate it.

```
Sub SolveItOnce()
Dim SetRng As Range, ChngRng As Range
Dim mySht As Worksheet

    Set mySht = ActiveSheet
    Worksheets("P2 Sample").Activate

    Set SetRng = Worksheets("P2 Sample").Range("Output")
    Set ChngRng = Worksheets("P2 Sample").Range("Input")

    SolverOk SetCell:=SetRng.Address, MaxMinVal:=3, ValueOf:=1, ByChange:=ChngRng.Address, Engine:=1
    SolverSolve UserFinish:=True

    mySht.Activate
    Set SetRng = Nothing
    Set ChngRng = Nothing
    Set mySht = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, tried your code, but still got the bug if I was on sheet 2. Here sheet2 is "P2 Result"

Comment: OK - I'll need to setup a test problem for it. Thanks.

Comment: The solver routines need some attention by MS. Updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks, so basically Solver has to handle sheet with objective and variable cells on it, right?