# VBA code to solve repeatedly

Tags: excel, solver, vba

I'm trying to write VBA code which repeatedly solves a objective function (cells in column P) by changing (cells in column H). Hereby I have the following constraints:

First constraint: `H_i <= H_i-1, e.g. H3 <= H2` and so on until the last row.

Second constraint: `L_i >= L_i-1, e.g. L3 >= L2` and so on until the last row.

The code so far:

```
Sub Solver_Balances()
'Automated solver to calculate the mass and heat balance
'at each time increment of 1 sec as given by the datalogger
'
Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate
RowCount = 2
Do While Not IsEmpty(Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("H" & RowCount))
    SolverReset
    SolverOk SetCell:=Range("P" & RowCount), MaxMinVal:=2, _
        ByChange:=Range("H" & RowCount), Engine:=1, _
        EngineDesc:="GRG Nonlinear"
    SolverAdd Cellref:=Range("H" & RowCount), _
        Relation:=1, _
        FormulaText:=Range("H" & RowCount - 1)
    SolverAdd Cellref:=Range("L" & RowCount), _
        Relation:=3, _
        FormulaText:=Range("L" & RowCount - 1)
    Solversolve userfinish:=True
    SolverFinish keepFinal:=1
    RowCount = RowCount + 1
Loop
End Sub
```

My value in **H2** is a starting value of `0.931` (a given value). For some reason my code replies a value of `0.53` in **H3**, where I expected to find a value much closer to `0.93`. Furthermore, my objective function is calculated on the basis of physical relationships in which value `0.53` is beneath a lower bound.

Can anyone tell me, if the code I'm using is correct? Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

After doing some adjustments, I manage to solve my problem.

Hereby the code:

```
Sub Solver_Balances()
'Automated solver to calculate the mass and heat balance
'at each time increment of 1 sec as given by the datalogger
'
Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate
RowCount = 2
Do While Not IsEmpty(Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("H" & RowCount))
    SolverReset
    SolverOk SetCell:="P" & RowCount, MaxMinVal:=2, ValueOf:=0, _
        ByChange:="H" & RowCount, Engine:=1, _
        EngineDesc:="GRG Nonlinear"
    SolverAdd CellRef:="H" & RowCount, _
        Relation:=1, _
        FormulaText:="H" & RowCount - 1
    SolverAdd CellRef:="L" & RowCount, _
        Relation:=3, _
        FormulaText:="L" & RowCount - 1
    SolverSolve userfinish:=True
    SolverFinish keepFinal:=1
    RowCount = RowCount + 1
Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: Getting the cell reference information to Solver is tricky. There are a number of other challenges ... [see the answer to this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36671991/use-solver-in-vba-with-loop-in-rows/36682703)