# Solver in VBA with loops and conditions

Tags: excel, vba, conditional-statements, solver

I'm a total newbi en VBA and Solver. I have made this Macro for Excel:

```
Sub Macro4()
'
' Macro4 Macro
' Mas4
'
'
SolverOk SetCell:="$CU$134", MaxMinVal:=3, ValueOf:=1, ByChange:="$BI$3", _
    Engine:=1, EngineDesc:="GRG Nonlinear"
SolverOk SetCell:="$CU$134", MaxMinVal:=3, ValueOf:=1, ByChange:="$BI$3", _
    Engine:=1, EngineDesc:="GRG Nonlinear"
SolverSolve UserFinish:=True
SolverOk SetCell:="$CV$134", MaxMinVal:=3, ValueOf:=1, ByChange:="$BJ$3", _
    Engine:=1, EngineDesc:="GRG Nonlinear"
SolverOk SetCell:="$CV$134", MaxMinVal:=3, ValueOf:=1, ByChange:="$BJ$3", _
    Engine:=1, EngineDesc:="GRG Nonlinear"
SolverSolve UserFinish:=True
SolverOk SetCell:="$CW$134", MaxMinVal:=3, ValueOf:=1, ByChange:="$BK$3", _
    Engine:=1, EngineDesc:="GRG Nonlinear"
SolverOk SetCell:="$CW$134", MaxMinVal:=3, ValueOf:=1, ByChange:="$BK$3", _
    Engine:=1, EngineDesc:="GRG Nonlinear"
SolverSolve UserFinish:=True
SolverOk SetCell:="$CX$134", MaxMinVal:=3, ValueOf:=1, ByChange:="$BL$3", _
    Engine:=1, EngineDesc:="GRG Nonlinear"
SolverOk SetCell:="$CX$134", MaxMinVal:=3, ValueOf:=1, ByChange:="$BL$3", _
    Engine:=1, EngineDesc:="GRG Nonlinear"
SolverSolve UserFinish:=True
SolverOk SetCell:="$CY$134", MaxMinVal:=3, ValueOf:=1, ByChange:="$BM$3", _
    Engine:=1, EngineDesc:="GRG Nonlinear"
SolverOk SetCell:="$CY$134", MaxMinVal:=3, ValueOf:=1, ByChange:="$BM$3", _
    Engine:=1, EngineDesc:="GRG Nonlinear"
SolverSolve UserFinish:=True
SolverOk SetCell:="$CZ$134", MaxMinVal:=3, ValueOf:=1, ByChange:="$BN$3", _
    Engine:=1, EngineDesc:="GRG Nonlinear"
SolverOk SetCell:="$CZ$134", MaxMinVal:=3, ValueOf:=1, ByChange:="$BN$3", _
    Engine:=1, EngineDesc:="GRG Nonlinear"
SolverSolve UserFinish:=True
SolverOk SetCell:="$DA$134", MaxMinVal:=3, ValueOf:=1, ByChange:="$BO$3", _
    Engine:=1, EngineDesc:="GRG Nonlinear"
SolverOk SetCell:="$DA$134", MaxMinVal:=3, ValueOf:=1, ByChange:="$BO$3", _
    Engine:=1, EngineDesc:="GRG Nonlinear"
SolverSolve UserFinish:=True

Range("BI3:BO3").Select
Selection.Copy

Range("DI134").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
End Sub
```

It works ok but only for the row 134. When the condition Q134 > 125 is meet then the Macro must be executed. I need to search for other Q rows that satisfied the condition Q(number of row) > 125, then the Macro should be executed but changing row 134 for "number of row" that satisfied the condition. I don't know how to pass this "numbre of row" to a reference for the Macro.

As you will see I need to save the Solver output each time the Macro is executed but I don't know how to do it. That's the reason why I have used:

```
Range("DI134").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
```

in the last part of my Macro.

Thanks in advance and sorry for my unexperience.

Comment: `don't know how to pass this "numbre of row"` use a variable.

Comment: looks like you are using SolverOk twice for each Solver run. One should suffice. I like using SolverReset to start clean. You need to add a step to copy the solution of each pass. You probably should use a VBA loop to o over the ranges of OF cells and DV cells.  
You can do the loop for the variable row number with something like this:    
`for i = 134 to 144`  
`if range("Q" & i).value > 125 then`  
`call macro4`  
`endif`  
`next i`

Comment: @E.Tron - please review the answer at [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36671991/use-solver-in-vba-with-loop-in-rows) and let me know if you have further questions.

Comment: @E.Tron - when you record a macro for doing a solver setup, it puts a call into SolverOK twice. It's not necessary to do this in your VBA.

Comment: Ok thanks, I'd seen that really there are instructions that appears two times. I've yet resolved this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Below is a routine that could do what you are interested in ...

```
Sub SolveRow(myRow As Long)
Dim iLoop As Long
Dim SetRng As Range, ChngRng As Range
Dim mySht As Worksheet
Dim SetAddress As String, ChngAddress As String
'
'
    Set mySht = Worksheets("Sheet4")
    For iLoop = 1 To 7
        Set SetRng = mySht.Range(mySht.Cells(myRow, iLoop + 98), mySht.Cells(myRow, iLoop + 98))
        SetAddress = Split(SetRng.Address(external:=True), "[")(0) & Split(SetRng.Address(external:=True), "]")(1)
        Set ChngRng = mySht.Range(mySht.Cells(3, iLoop + 60), mySht.Cells(3, iLoop + 60))
        ChngAddress = Split(ChngRng.Address(external:=True), "[")(0) & Split(ChngRng.Address(external:=True), "]")(1)

        SolverOk SetCell:=SetAddress, MaxMinVal:=3, ValueOf:=1, ByChange:=ChngAddress, Engine:=1
        SolverSolve UserFinish:=True
    Next iLoop

    mySht.Range("BI3:BO3").Copy
    mySht.Range("DI" & myRow).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False

    Set mySht = Nothing
End Sub
```

This can be called by another VBA routine that determines which row needs to be calculated. e.g. ...

```
Sub main()
Dim theRow As Long
    theRow = 134
    SolveRow (theRow)
End Sub
```

Let's break down the `SolveRow` sub. On the line ...

```
Set mySht = Worksheets("Sheet4")
```

... you should change "Sheet4" to be the name of the worksheet containing your formulas.

The loop ...

```
For iLoop = 1 To 7
   ...
Next iLoop
```

... does 7 iterations. The number you had in your original code.

The lines determining the value for `SetCell` are ...

```
    Set SetRng = mySht.Range(mySht.Cells(myRow, iLoop + 98), mySht.Cells(myRow, iLoop + 98))
    SetAddress = Split(SetRng.Address(external:=True), "[")(0) & Split(SetRng.Address(external:=True), "]")(1)
```

... the first line defines the range. 'iLoop + 98' goes from 99 to 105, which corresponds to columns CU to DA. The second line evaluates to a string with the fully qualified range - it will be something like `Sheet4!$CU$134`.

The lines determining the value for `ByChange` are ...

```
    Set ChngRng = mySht.Range(mySht.Cells(3, iLoop + 60), mySht.Cells(3, iLoop + 60))
    ChngAddress = Split(ChngRng.Address(external:=True), "[")(0) & Split(ChngRng.Address(external:=True), "]")(1)
```

... it appears that you are always changing values in row 3, so it is hard coded. `iLoop + 60` will correspond to columns BI through BO.

Note:

- SolverReset is not invoked. It causes problems with setting manual calculation mode.
- In SolverOK, only `Engine:=1` is specified. If you specify both `Engine:=1, EngineDesc:="GRG Nonlinear"` you will get unexpected behavior. (the problem does not get redefined, and the first problem will get solved 7 times).

The two lines, pretty much what you had, ...

```
mySht.Range("BI3:BO3").Copy
mySht.Range("DI" & myRow).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
```

... do the copy / paste operation. Again, I assume you always want the third row copied, so the range is hard coded. If it should be otherwise, techniques used above can be used to specify the correct range. I also assume you want to paste in the same row you did the Solver calc's in.

Comment: uffff, I think your level is too high for my knowledge. But thanks I all case.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will take a glance at it but it surpass a too much my knowledge in VBA.

Answer (score 0):

I think that I've found how to pass the cell numbers as reference. For example SolverOk SetCell:="CU" & i

Now my macro is like this and it works ok:

```
Sub Macro7()

Dim i As Long
Dim k As Long
k = 0
Dim s As Long
s = 1

For i = 8 To 77806
k = k + 1

If Range("Q" & i) > 125 Then
s = i - k + 1
k = 0

SolverOk SetCell:="CU" & i, MaxMinVal:=3, ValueOf:=1, ByChange:="$BI$3", _
    Engine:=1, EngineDesc:="GRG Nonlinear"
SolverSolve UserFinish:=True
SolverOk SetCell:="CV" & i, MaxMinVal:=3, ValueOf:=1, ByChange:="$BJ$3", _
    Engine:=1, EngineDesc:="GRG Nonlinear"
SolverSolve UserFinish:=True
SolverOk SetCell:="CW" & i, MaxMinVal:=3, ValueOf:=1, ByChange:="$BK$3", _
    Engine:=1, EngineDesc:="GRG Nonlinear"
SolverSolve UserFinish:=True
SolverOk SetCell:="CX" & i, MaxMinVal:=3, ValueOf:=1, ByChange:="$BL$3", _
    Engine:=1, EngineDesc:="GRG Nonlinear"
SolverSolve UserFinish:=True
SolverOk SetCell:="CY" & i, MaxMinVal:=3, ValueOf:=1, ByChange:="$BM$3", _
    Engine:=1, EngineDesc:="GRG Nonlinear"
SolverSolve UserFinish:=True
SolverOk SetCell:="CZ" & i, MaxMinVal:=3, ValueOf:=1, ByChange:="$BN$3", _
    Engine:=1, EngineDesc:="GRG Nonlinear"
SolverSolve UserFinish:=True
SolverOk SetCell:="DA" & i, MaxMinVal:=3, ValueOf:=1, ByChange:="$BO$3", _
    Engine:=1, EngineDesc:="GRG Nonlinear"
SolverSolve UserFinish:=True

Range("BI3:BO3").Select
Selection.Copy
Range("DI" & i).Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
Range("CU" & i & ":DA" & i).Select
Selection.Copy
Range("DB" & i).Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False

Range("BP" & s & ":BV" & i).Select
Selection.Copy
Range("DP" & s).Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
End If

Next i

End Sub
```

As you can see I've added other things I needed.

Thanks a lot everybody. Good forum.